# Cannot increment properly in primary key when its datatype is varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Ii want to generate a primary key like 'A-1','A-2','A-3'...upto 'A-1000'. The datatype of this column is varchar(7) and table name is sesson. I used substring query like max(substring(id,3,4)) as max_id.increament is done in front end code. My query working properly from 'A-1' to 'A-10'. When 'A-10' is save in database then it show '9' as max_id but it should display '10' as max_id. what changes are required to do this?

```
select max(substring(id,3,4)) as max_id from sesson
```

When 'A-10' is saved then it should display '10' as max_id but it show '9' as max_id.

Comment: Why not simply have an integer primary key column? With "auto increment".'

Comment: Use a number datatype (integer/number) as primary key id or use, if you really need it, a primary key of 2 columns, id (number)  and ... prefix(varchar(1)). That way you can easily increment the number without any substring operations

Comment: because my requirement is that three category of people A,B,C when A category people reaches 566 then primary key'A-566' and then insert people of B categoy then it starts from 'B-1' and same like 'C-1'

Comment: Varchar is a kind of common type String. The order of string values is different to numbers.

Comment: So 1900-ish. Have a composite 2 column primary key then.

Comment: So you build the primary key by selecting the current max value and adding 1 to it for the new pk value? Have you considered that two clients might get a new value at the same time and then get the same number? You should use what ever way the database supports to generate unique numbers (sequence, auto increment, ...)

Comment: Dont use the primary key as a displayed value and use a seperate column like `Type(varchar2(1))` for your person types. If you really need to number your persons you should either number each list you generate or have a seperate column. If you only need the total count, count it upon fetching data. A key is something to (uniquely) identify data, not to represend certain properties of it.

Comment: yes..you are correct now i increament in database rather than front end..

Comment: MSSQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use to_number before the max function as shown below.

```
select max(to_number(substr(id,3,4))) as max_id from sesson
```

by default system will consider the result of the substring as a string.. hence the max value will be calculated based on ascii value .. character by character. So, 9 will have the highest ascii value than 10(as system will compare based on character by character, 9 will be compared with 1)

Comment: it show the error :'to_number' is not a recognized built-in function name.........please tell what is "to_number"

Comment: to_number function will convert the inputted character to number.. can you confirm which DB are you using.. this to_number function which I had referred is from oracle db.. function name may vary in other database but there will be similar functions..

Comment: yesss...it working correctly....thank you soo Much...In MSSQL server the query is select max (cast( substring(id,3,4)as int )) as id  from sesson...

Answer (score 0):

Convert the value to a number.  In SQL Server, you do:

```
select max(try_convert(int, substring(id, 3, 4))) as max_id
from sesson
```